# If I have the Battle Pass and a bundle from the item shop, will my progress still save when my PlayStation Plus subscription expires?

Tags: playstation-plus, call-of-duty-black-ops-cold-war

I have both the Battle Pass and a bundle for Call of Duty: Cold War. Will my progress still save after my PlayStation Plus subscription expires?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be allowed to do the "extra" battle pass or the gold pass, whatever it is called, but your bundles should save. I got a bundle free and then it became buy again the next day and I kept it so the same should happen to you. Progress should save to (until the season is over and the battle pass resets)
I could be wrong as I don't buy much on the PS4 but I hope this will possibly help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PS saves all your progress at 2 places: one is on PS Plus cloud storage and also on your console storage. So make sure you do not delete your progress from cloud storage and console storage. Even with the help of cloud storage you can play your progressed data from other console.

If you delete any game from your console and you do not delete save data from console storage or cloud storage, whenever you re-download the game you will get all your progress data back.
By default if you delete any game from your console your data remain saved, until and unless you want to delete your progress data by going into storage settings or cloud storage settings.